# Pokemon go is not working

Tags: pokemon-go

Today, i stopped at 4 different pokestops multiple times but couldnt get any pokeballs. My bag is not full but it just spins but not give anything. I am using pokemon trainer club account. We do use the same account on 2 iphones (and both have the same problem).

Comment: Did you "stop" or did you "drive by and spin"? There was a server-side change recently that prevents you from getting anything from Pokestops if you are moving faster than a brisk walking pace.

Answer (score 0):

- If it spins normally and nothing pops up, it may just be a temporary glitch (this happened to me quite a few times, even before the speed change)
- If it spins normally and "Try again later" pops up, you're going too fast and won't be able receive any items. You also won't be able to catch any pokemon (no sightings will appear).
- If you try to spin it and it stops automatically in a split-second, and "Try again later" pops up, you may have been here before (the Poke-stop won't be blue) recently.

Answer (score -1):

You might have been soft banned by Niantic for going too fast or being suspected of using GPS spoofing.

Soft bans last from a few hours up to a week, depending on how fast and how far you've went, so you might have to give it some time before you try again.